# Using lodash with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I have found an app online using AngularJS with Lodash.
The way Lodash is included is simply by adding to the body the following line (after having included angular):

```
<script src='vendor/lodash/3.3.1/lodash.min.js'></script>
<script src='myApp.js'></script>
```

Inside myApp.js, the first line is :

```
/* global angular, _ */
```

And then you have access to Lodash (using _)
I am not sure to understand why it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lodash includes itself](https://lodash.com/#installation) on the global scope level. It does so by attaching `_`
 to the `window` object ([see code here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/dist/lodash.js#L15071)).
That comment line you're seeing has nothing to do with this. It's a configuration line for a linter like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/docs/#inline-configuration), so it doesn't throw errors at you because it thinks those variables are `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

I would include lodash the following way.

Include it in index.html before angular,  just like You did (although I prefer using bower command,which would make it available globally). And Have constant in your module

```
angular.module('sampleApp', [])
    .constant('_', _);
```

Inject it into your controller or angular component. Hope this helps.

```
.controller('sampleAppController', function ($scope) {
  $scope._ = _;
})
```

Also, You can attach it to rootScope, I wouldn't prefer doing it though.